# Ruby on Rails creating a dummy object to be used later as a user object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Member.rb:

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
```

controller:

```
def add_member
    @group = Group.find(session[:group_id])
    @mem = @group.members.create(member_params)
    @mem.status = "Pending"
    if @mem.save
        token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
        @mem.token = token
        if @mem.save
            @message = @group.sentMessages.new
            @message.save
            @message.send_new_member_email(@mem)
        end
        redirect_to group_path
    else
        @members = @group.members
        render 'show'
    end
end
```

I have a `Member` object that gets created by the group owner. This is essentially a dummy object that holds some data and invites the member to join the group.

From there the user receiving the notification has the option to create an account. I would like them to simply enter a password (we already have their email) to create this account.

The group owner was able to create objects and the notifications went out, however once I added the password fields the group owner was no longer able to do this. When the form is submitted the page renders again with the fields still populated and it shows a new object as created. If you refresh the page, however, the object disappears and the fields are blank again. It seems like `if @mem.save` is failing but I am not sure why and this does not explain the object seemingly being created.. I thought `allow_blank: true` and `allow_nil: true` would have solved this but I am still experiencing the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't you use CRUD routes? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html chapter 2.2

Comment: Could that be the issue?

Comment: nope, just reminding you abour rails pracitses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_secure_password
```

Is the source of your problems here.  According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)  It comes with the validations of the presence of the password, as well as the confirmation of password via `password_confirmation`

But the good news is, according to the docs you can negate those validations like so:

```
has_secure_password(validations: false)
```

This should work for you